# Reading chart data from a powerpoint file

Tags: vbscript, powerpoint

I have a pptx file which has text, tables and charts. I am trying to automate validation of the data contained in the file using VBScript (not VBA or VB).

I am able to read all the text and table data but unable to read the chart data. Can someone help me to understand how to go about reading pptx chart data using vbscript?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

Office 2007 - Slide.Shape.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1) contains the chart data.